# Compile gsoap-onvif solve #error: ‘M_ASN1_STRING_data’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, openssl, gsoap, onvif

I'm trying to compile the gsoap-onvif project here: https://github.com/xris-hu/gsoap-onvif

I call the make file and it throws some errors. Working on ubuntu 18.10 i solved some of them installing the dependencies: g++, gsoap, libssl-dev.
Unfortunately I have an error which I cannot understand:

```
admin@UbuntuOS:~/Desktop/gsoap-onvif-master$ make
g++ -c -Wall -g -w -fPIC -DWITH_NONAMESPACES -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fexceptions -DWITH_DOM  -DWITH_OPENSSL -DSOAP_DEBUG   -I./include -I. stdsoap2.cpp -o stdsoap2.o
stdsoap2.cpp: In function ‘int tcp_connect(soap*, const char*, const char*, int)’:
stdsoap2.cpp:4406:52: error: ‘M_ASN1_STRING_data’ was not declared in this scope
             { if (!soap_tag_cmp(host, (const char*)M_ASN1_STRING_data(name)))
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
stdsoap2.cpp:4406:52: note: suggested alternative: ‘ASN1_STRING_data’
             { if (!soap_tag_cmp(host, (const char*)M_ASN1_STRING_data(name)))
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                    ASN1_STRING_data
make: *** [Makefile:22: stdsoap2.o] Error 1
```

Someone know how to solve this issue?

UPDATE: the version of gSOAP used in this project is pretty old and may not work with newer versions of OpenSSL. 
The project could be dead... Anyone knows an alternative?

ALTERNATIVE: Here is the best solution I found: https://github.com/suresecure/onvifcpplib
This lib is used also in https://sourceforge.net/projects/onvifmanager/

Comment: It might be that your installed openssl version is old.

Comment: I have the latest version (v1.1.1) on Ubuntu 18.10, installed through apt-get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seams it is a OpenSSL/gsoap isseus, try to update the software with a new version of stdsoap2.cpp.

https://github.com/Sufi-Al-Hussaini/onvif-gsoap-by-example/issues/1

Comment: UPDATE: the version of gSOAP used in this project is pretty old and may not work with newer versions of OpenSSL.

Answer (score 0):

In Python a very nice solution is the following project on GitHub:

> https://github.com/FalkTannhaeuser/python-onvif-zeep

an alternative for python 2.x is:

> https://github.com/quatanium/python-onvif.

Comment: This is not a solution to the compilation problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a patch that I've successfully used, which is based on newer gSOAP 2.8 versions that use the following source code:

```
#if OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER < 0x10100000L
              const char *tmp = (const char*)ASN1_STRING_data(name);
#else
              const char *tmp = (const char*)ASN1_STRING_get0_data(name);
#endif
              if (!soap_tag_cmp(host, tmp))
              {
                ok = 1;
                DBGLOG(TEST, SOAP_MESSAGE(fdebug, "SSL: host name %s match with certificate subject %s\n", host, tmp));
              }
```

This patch works with older gSOAP versions.

This edit is made to stdsoap2.c and stdsoap2.cpp in function `tcp_connect()`, which is pretty long.

Comment: Which version of openssl did you used?
And in which file I must put the code that you posted?

Comment: This edit is made to stdsoap2.c and stdsoap2.cpp in function tcp_connect(), which is pretty long.

Answer (score 0):

It's the **libssl1.0** library problem

Go to this [link](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4764), find an answer from username **saberprashant**, and follow his steps. The problem might be solved.